# Word2Vecにおけるマイナスの概念について

Tags: python, 機械学習, 自然言語処理, word2vec

Word2Vecでsimilarityの値がマイナスになるのはどうしてなのでしょうか？
たとえば、次のコードを実行した時に、meowが-0.018となり、マイナスになっています。
この場合100次元空間のベクトルの内積ですから、マイナスではなくてプラスになると思っています。
今回はmeowだけでしたが、sizeのパラメーターを変更すると他のものもマイナスになったりします。

### ソースコード

```
# sourcecode
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
sentences = [["cat", "say", "meow"],["dog","say","woof"]]
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1,size=100)
print(model.wv.most_similar(positive=['cat']))

# output
[('woof', 0.12968875467777252),
('say', 0.06406527757644653),
('dog', 0.05123840644955635),
('meow', -0.01819145306944847)]
```

### 参考にしたページ

ページ中部のExample
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回お使いのライブラリの API ドキュメントによると、[`most_similar()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Doc2VecKeyedVectors.most_similar) は[コサイン尺度](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)から類似度を判定するようです。コサイン尺度は 2 つのベクトルの内積と符号が同じであり、距離とは異なりマイナスにも成り得ます。特に 2 つのベクトルの成す角が鈍角のときに負値となります。